# does the json file contain more private info

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I give away the google-services.json to my outsourced developer so that he can build the component that interacts with Firestore, am I giving away too much info? The Firestore db I have is still in develeopment mode and I was planning once eveyrhting is done  is to create a new firestore db but I am worried that the json file has more information that is needed for testing.

Let me know how you would handle such situation
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service account will contain full access to your Cloud Firestore database, using the Firebase Admin SDK.  You can revoke the account once your developer has completed their work and they'll have no more access.

There's a good chance that you'll need to keep developing new features.  I'd recommend creating multiple projects:

- myProject-dev
- myProject-alpha
- myProject-beta
- myProject-stable

You can then create separate branches in your Git repository and ensure that you **do not** include any service accounts in your repository.  Keep them stored separately and use environment variables to connect.

### Service account using environment variable example

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = process.env.MY_CREDENTIALS;

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(JSON.parse(serviceAccount))
});
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

Then you can set the environment variable for testing, with: `export MY_CREDENTIALS=$(cat ./path/to/service/account.json)`

If you need to access Cloud FIrestore from within the same GCP project (Compute Engine instance / Kubernetes / Cloud Functions), then you shouldn't need to provide the service account key.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's great suggestion